# IIS is not serving my static file on Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, lets-encrypt

I have a static file, letsencrypt.txt, in the wwwroot folder on my website.
But going to http://{domain}.com/letsencrypt.txt gives 404.

This is not on a virtual machine, shared or otherwise. I do not have root access or CPanel access. I do not have any extra Azure Storage.

I do have a Subscription, a Resource Group, an App Service, an App Service Plan, and an API Management Service. I do have FTP access, so I can see the file structure and upload files and download log files.

In practice, all I really know is that the file is at /site/wwwroot.

The log shows

```
<tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>https://{domain}:80/letsencrypt.txt</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>**C:\home\site\wwwroot\letsencrypt.txt**</td></tr>
```

which is exactly where I think the file is located.
I can't see any reason for it to not be able to find the file.
Nothing in the log about access control or permissions.

I thought that perhaps the https issue was a result of the DNS redirect, but I get the same 404 if I go directly to {domain}.azurewebsites.net. And it still redirects to https.

One interesting point is that, here in the log, it specifies port 80 even though it says https.

Here is the entire web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\SmartTagsAPI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
      <rewrite> 
        <rules> 
<!--           <rule name="wildcard"> 
            <match url=".*well-known/acme-challenge/(?!.*?\.txt$)(.*)$" /> 
            <action type="Redirect" url="LetsEncrypt/letsencrypt.txt" /> 
          </rule>  -->
        </rules> 
      </rewrite> 
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Azure has tons of services to host web apps, so you should edit the question and make it very clear how you hosted yours, in Azure App Service, or simply on a virtual machine of yours.

Comment: @LexLi I don't know enough about Azure to intelligently answer your question, so I threw some details at you. Let me know if more clarification would be helpful.

Comment: "this is not on a virtual machine, shared or otherwise" - sure it is. You just don't manage it when it's in Azure App Service, Microsoft manages it for you.

Comment: If you are actually using Azure App Service (Windows) to host the web apps, then please use the managed certificates provided for free, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal They are equivalent to Let's Encrypt certificates in many ways but under SLA, and you don't need any extra configuration either. BTW, Azure App Service builds up a special build of Windows/IIS, but all questions related to that should tag with azure-web-app-service for clarity.

Comment: @LexLi They are provided for free, provided you spend $50/mo more.  I'm in the D1 tier, which doesn't support custom TLS/SSL. Since I can't use theirs, I'm trying to add my own.

Comment: And thanks for the tip on azure-web-app-service.

Comment: D1 does not support custom SSL binding, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal#check-the-pricing-tier So, Let's Encrypt won't work either, as even if you find a way to generate the certificate, you cannot install it to D1 plan. If really want to use D1 plan, set up a service like Cloudflare in front which offers you free certificates.

Comment: @LexLi Can you write this as an answer so I can mark it such? CF worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

As you revealed more information, this question becomes more like "how to set up free certificates for Azure App Service D1 plan".

D1 does not support custom SSL binding, [which is by design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex%2Cportal#check-the-pricing-tier). So, Let's Encrypt won't work either, as even if you find a way to generate the certificate, you cannot install it to D1 plan.

Like you tested, you can alternatively set up a service like Cloudflare in front which offers you free certificates.

Comment: You're right, that your answer answered my problem but not the original question I asked. Should I change the question?